# Selenium Python: How to click button

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, click, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click

```
<div class="accBtn button buttonP" onclick="registerAcc()">Register</div>
```

if you visit `krunker.io` and inspect and then just ctrl f **Register** you should find it.

Here is my code:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"Register").click()
```

and the error is "no such element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**Krunker**](https://krunker.io/) website uses [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) calls.

---

### Solution

To click on the element <kbd>Register</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://krunker.io/'})
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='signedOutHeaderBar' and contains(., 'Login or Register')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='accBtn button buttonP' and text()='Register']"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very content-heavy website, so a way to interact with it would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://krunker.io'

browser.get(url)

WebDriverWait(browser, 200000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
print('Accepted terms')
WebDriverWait(browser, 200000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// div[contains(text(), 'Login or Register')]"))).click()
print('clicked login/register')
WebDriverWait(browser, 200000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"buttonP"))).click()
print('clicked Register button')
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to open **krunker.io**, and found out the register not like what you discribed.
as u discribed in your questions, the right code is:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"accBtn button buttonP").click()
```

compare with my code and your code, you will find out that the class name is just behind "div class="

besides, you will need to find the right html codes position before the code works